# Rails_Admin - How to change size of text field in the Post view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

The default height for the input area on the "body" of a Post in Rails Admin is pretty small. I'm trying to figure out how to increase the height. Any suggestions?

```
config.model Post do
 label 'Blog'
 weight 0
 edit do
   field :user
   field :title
   field :body_format
   field :body do 
     (something here?)
  end
```

Answer (score 11):

```
configure :description do
  html_attributes rows: 20, cols: 50
end
```

Comment: This works correctly.  Place it inside your rails_admin do block inside your model, replacing :description with the field you want to modify the text block form element for.

Comment: This is an ok solution but the text field does not adapt to the size of screen. A fullscreen option would be nice.

Answer (score 4):

Another way of increasing the length of the text field in Rails Admin is:

```
field :description, :text do
  html_attributes do
    {:maxlength => 600}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

in case of text field, you will do like this

```
field :permalink do
  { max_length: 1000 }
end
```

and in case of text area

```
field :description do
  html_attributes rows: 5, cols: 100
end
```

As I have done for my own website i.e. https://www.wiki11.com
Hopefully, this will help you. Just remember, since text fields can contain 255 characters only, so it cant go upto text area's width. In order to reach up to text area width, you will need to change its character's length or make it text area.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have anything to do with your model, what you're needing to do is change the CSS for that element. Many of the Rails engines tend to "hide" the css from you, but it's often better to leave them alone anyway and make changes in your own custom.css file (or custom.css.scss if you're using SASS).

The easiest way is to look at the page in Chrome, right click on the "body" element and when the popup menu shows, go down to Inspect Element. The Chrome developer tools window will open below and that element will be highlighted. Look at the css class on the right to see what is being called.

Go into your custom.css file and write a new version of that css class. You might use that exact same name, but it's better to write your own class that is added to that specific html element or you'll override more than you want.

```
input, textarea .yourclassname {
  height: 200px;
}
```

If something like that doesn't work. Add the !important. (Better to leave it out if it's not needed.)

```
input, textarea .yourclassname {
  height: 200px !important;
}
```